# How can I rename a file I have to upload and save to folder

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to upload an image and save it to `storage/app/logos`.

And I want to rename it with the information that the user inserts on the input. I have already done a `dd();` and it works well.

I have already tried to change the save as. But when it comes to save the file on the folder it saves an unreadable file and named `$name`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="emp" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    Book title:
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="title" />
    <br /><br />
    Logo:
    <br />
    <input type="file" name="logo" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value=" Save " />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my controller:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class empController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('title');
        $request->logo->storeAs('logos', '$name');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quoting the variable name so it becomes a string

```php
$request->file('logo')->storeAs('logos', $name);
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/filesystem#file-uploads)

**Specifying A File Name**
If you would not like a file name to be automatically assigned to your stored file, you may use the `storeAs` method, which receives the path, the file name, and the (optional) disk as its arguments:

```php
$path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs(
    'avatars', $request->user()->id
);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

in case you want to do it on your own:

```
// initializing file name with null
$data['logo'] = null;

if ($request->hasFile("logo")) {
        $fileName = md5(time() . rand()) . "." . pathinfo($request->photo- 
                    >getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $destinationPath = storage_path('/app/logos/');
        $request->photo->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
        $data['logo'] = $fileName; // storing filename
}
```